# Warn when code throws a string instead of an error

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Sometimes in JavaScript, people will write `throw 'Something went wrong';` instead of `throw Error('something went wrong');`

The first example is totally valid JS, but is not ideal because strings don't have stack traces, but errors do. Can the Closure Compiler warn when code is throwing strings instead of throwing errors?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a JS Conformance file. Full details are [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Zx-p-GmgPIEig26dFV4Iy9u6wTOLem8o7ScaqT66lA/view), but essentially you create a file `js_conformance.txt`:

```
requirement: {
  type: BANNED_CODE_PATTERN
  error_message: 'The use of throw with a string is not allowed. Throw an Error object instead.'

  value: '/** @param {string|String} str */ function template(str) { throw str }'
}
```

and pass it to the compiler using `--conformance_configs=js_conformance.txt`

If there are a lot of existing `throw 'string'`s in your codebase, you can clean them up using [RefasterJS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14-rsX1-VoTN2lpFalbwr4_yupxXYW-qNYn2XGVvhLwE/view).

[This video is a nice intro to both the conformance checks and RefasterJS.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXZaqHWq6cM)

Comment: There is a custom conformance rule for this that allows for rethrowing